# Pointer arithmetic disguised &(array[0])

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Today I browsed some source code (it was an example file explaining the use of a software framework) and discovered a lot of code like this:

```
int* array = new int[10]; // or malloc, who cares. Please, no language wars. This is applicable to both languages
for ( int* ptr = &(array[0]); ptr <= &(array[9]); ptr++ )
{
   ...
}
```

So basically, they've done "take the address of the object that lies at address `array + x`".

Normally I would say, that this is plain stupidity, as writing `array + 0`or `array + 9` directly does the same. I even would always rewrite such code to a size_t for loop, but that's a matter of style.

But the overuse of this got me thinking: Am I missing something blatantly obvious or something subtely hidden in the dark corners of the language?

For anyone wanting to take a look at the original source code, with all it's nasty `goto`s , `malloc`s and of course this pointer thing, feel free to [look at it online](http://scip.zib.de/doc/examples/TSP/GomoryHuTree_8cpp_source.shtml).

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. Sometimes silly code is just silly code. Look at all the people who write `>> 1` to divide something by two and spend weeks celebrating their on ingenuity.

Comment: `goto`'s (or any control flow modifications) are generally bad practice (i.e. spaghetti code) but are often found in OS kernel code (for good reason/optimization purposes).

Comment: Potentially it could have been ported from another language, or even converted automatically (I've seen code converted from Fortran that looks like this). Sometimes it's more expedient to use the equivalent constructs that exist in both languages than try to rewrite from scratch using best practices.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall This is a nice point, maybe you're right about that! I doubt it, since the framework is written in C (with a few extensions for C++) only. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You're not missing anything, they do mean the same thing. However, to try to shed some light on this, I should say that I also write expressions like that occasionally, for clarity. I tend to think in OO terms, meaning that I prefer to express "the address of the `i`th element of the array", rather than "the `i`th offset from the beginning address of the array". Perhaps that's the reasoning of the person who wrote this as well.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Back in the day (which sounds daft when you're still under 30, but all the same :)), and at the risk of appearing suitably silly, shifts did sometimes make a performance difference. I seem to recall doing `(y << 8) + (y << 6) + x` instead of `y * 320 + x` on a 320 x 200 display - and it being faster.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: That's a fairly reasonable way to think about it. thank you, this never occured to me. Do you mind putting that as an answer so I can upvote this? ;-)

Comment: @stefan Sure, just did. Thanks. =)

Comment: @KerrekSB: On 99% of C compilers, if `x` is signed, the `x>>1` will perform a computation which is different from, and in many cases more useful than, `x/2`.  In cases where the floored division result is required, I would consider `x>>1` as being much clearer than any alternative that would yield the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything, they do mean the same thing.

However, to try to shed some more light on this, I should say that I also write expressions like that from time to time, for added clarity.

I personally tend to think in terms of object-oriented programming, meaning that I prefer to refer to "the address of the `n`th element of the array", rather than "the `n`th offset from the beginning address of the array". Even though those two things are equivalent in C, when I'm writing the code, I have the former in mind - so I express that.

Perhaps that's the reasoning of the person who wrote this as well.

Comment: Accepted for beeing the first one to mention the OOP idea behind this, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, there's no good reason for the first one.  This is exactly the same thing:

```
int *ptr = array;
```

I agree on the second also, may as well just write:

```
ptr < (array + 10)
```

Of course you could also just make it a `for` loop from 0-9 and set the temp pointer to point to the beginning of the array.

```
for(int i = 0, *ptr = array; i < 10; ++i, ++ptr)
    /* ... */
```

That of course assumes that `ptr` is not being modified within the body of the loop.

Comment: Even better: just set (and if possible, declare) the pointer in the loop body.

Comment: Can't you also put the pointer within the init expression of the for-loop? `for(int i = 0, *ptr = array; i < 10; ++i, ++ptr)`

Comment: @leemes: Yep, you could.  That would limit its scope, probably a good idea.

Comment: Even better: `ptr < array + 10`. No parentheses needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't agree that parentheses make the expression any "worse".

Comment: (@EdS.) (((I'm) (on a campaign)) ((to get rid) (of unneeded parentheses))). (<g>).

Comment: @PeteBecker: Well that's a bit extreme.  I like the parens in this case.  You can write your code however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this is *partially* incorrect. Read the comments.

---

The problem with `&(array[0])` is that it expands to `&(*(array + 0))` which involves an dereference. Now, every compiler will obviously optimize this into the same thing as `array + 0`, but as far as the language is concerned the dereference can cause UB in places where `array + 0` would not.

Comment: I was thinking about that too :D This would make up a funny follow-up question: "Which compiler is crazy enough to detect such nonsense?"

Comment: It doesn't involve a dereference, at least in C. 6.5.3.2 (3): "Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator."

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow, so they really did thought of such things in the standard. Seems like a waste of time to me, but still wonderful to see this!

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, it seems I was mistaken then. I'll delete this in a few minutes so other people can see your comment.

Comment: @Pubby Your answer is correct for C90, as far as I know. The text Daniel Fischer quoted is new in C99.

Comment: @stefan It's necessary for `&array[10]` to work, so it must be mentioned in the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer: In the case of `&array[10]`, why wouldn't it be the normal extension of `array[10]` to `*(array + 10)` first and then the address `&`. Or is this an example of maximal munch(?) taking it as (&array)[10]?

Comment: @stefan `array + 10` is the pointer one past the end. You can compute it, but dereferencing it would be UB. So if `&array[i]` involved a dereference, `&array[i]` and `array + i` wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: @hvd It seems your memory is correct. The document that is supposed to be a copy of the C89 standard I found on the net doesn't contain that text.

Comment: @DanielFischer So it seems I'm definitively too tired. I didn't even think of `10` beeing an non-arbitrarily chosen number (because I made it up in the question without thinking about it). Thanks again and good night ;-)

Comment: @DanielFischer (Somehow misread your comment at first.) In fairness, that's a nit, though. No practical implementation would dereference `p` in `&*p`, only to discard its result. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why they wrote it this way was that

```
&(array[0])
```

and

```
&(array[9])
```

just look similar. Another way would be to write it

```
array + 0
```

and

```
array + 9
```

respectively. As you already mentioned, they essentially do the same (at least most compilers treat it as the same, I hope).

You could interpret the two different type of expressions differently: The first one can be read as "the address of element 0 / 9". The second one can be read as "array pointer with an element offset of 0 / 9". The first one sounds more high-level, the second more low-level. However, most people tend to use the second form, though.

Now since `array + 0` of course is the same as `array`, you could just write `array`. I think the point here is that the begin and end of the loop look "analogous" to each other. A question of personal taste.

Comment: So do bare `0` and `9` when you just use a loop counter.

Comment: I would simply use `for (ptr=array; ptr < array + 9 ; ptr++ ){...}`

Comment: yes @leemes yes i was stating my preference only.. Preferably something simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

According to classical mathematics:

```
Array[n]
```

refers to the *nth* element in the array.

To "take the address of" the *nth* element, the `&` or `address of` operator is applied:

```
  &Array[n]
```

To clear out any assumed ambiguities, parenthesis are added:

```
  &(Array[n])
```

To a reader, reading from left to right, this expression has the meaning:
    *Return the address of the element at position 'n'*

The insurance may have developed as a protection against old faulty compilers.

Some people consider it more readable than:

```
  Array + n
```

Sorry, but I am old school and prefer using the '&' version, paren or without.  I'll waste my time making code easier to read than worrying about which version takes longer to compile or which version is more efficient.

A clear commented section of code has a higher Return On Investment than a section of code that is micro-optimized for efficiency or uses sections of the language that are unfamilar to non language lawyers.

Comment: No need to apologize at all. As it boils down to the very same (given some optimization of a compiler), it is in fact a personal preference.